# Why doesn't my Linux machine use swap?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, java, swap

I have a java application in a Tomcat application server that uses extreme amounts of memory - let's say 45GB.
I have 32GB RAM + 32GB of Swap on my Ubuntu 16.04 64bit PC. I'm starting the application with -Xmx48g, so I would expect it to fill up my memory and then start "swapping". Unfortunately my PC locks up once memory is full - even though the swap is still completely empty. Why is that?

Comment: If the PC is locked up, how do you know the swap space is empty?

Comment: I had the system monitor open in the moment the system locked up

Comment: Assuming your swap is correctly configured (check with `free -h`), you may have too low a swappiness value (check with `cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness`): I don't recommend a value less than `10`. Otherwise, the Java engine may be locking pages into memory: have you tried without the `-Xmx48g` option?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My swappiness is 60, without the Xmx I run out of memory far more quickly.

Comment: And the free command claims I have 31G of swap with 0B used and 31G Memory with 10G used, 14G free, 1,7G shared and 7,2G buffer/cache - it's fine that it doesn't use swap right now, but as I approach my memory limit, I would expect it start swapping.

Comment: Very puzzling. With a swappiness of 60, my Ubuntu (16.04, 64-bit - like yours) is all too ready to swap and I've reduced it to 10. My reference for swapping is [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq): some of the commands here may give a clue to what is going on.